# Playwright's request.sizes() returns negative responseBodySize

Tags: playwright

I've noticed that in certain cases, Playwright's request.sizes() function returns negative responseBodySize values for some requests. Upon further analysis using browser developer tools, it became evident that these requests either are served from cache or are associated with Azure Blob requests ("resource Type-image"). Is this an expected behavior?

Code snippet for reference-

```
const handleRequest = async request => {
    const initiatorFrame = request.frame();
    const initiatorFrameUrl = initiatorFrame ? initiatorFrame.url() : "Unknown";
    if (initiatorFrameUrl === "Unknown") {
      console.log("Request from ", request.url(), initiatorFrameUrl);
    }
    const response = await request.response();

    if (response) {
      const responseSizes = await request.sizes();
      const requestEntry = {
        method: request.method(),
        domain: new URL(request.url()).hostname,
        url: request.url(),
        size: responseSizes.responseBodySize,
        status: response.status(),
        statusSuccess: response.ok(),
        fromServiceWorker: response.fromServiceWorker(),
        resourceType: response.request().resourceType(),
        frame: initiatorFrameUrl,
      };
      entries.push(requestEntry);
    } else {
      console.log("No response from ", request.url());
    }
  };
```

Comment: Can you give an code example of an public facing  web site for the point you are claiming  here?

Comment: @VishalAggarwal I am trying to capture requests from teams.microsoft.com. On launching teams, the page subscribes to request event and captures the information in an array. I have added the code snippet in the post. Any thoughts?

Comment: Seems like a bug. This might help - https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/23750